# Error in matplotlib csv2rec function

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

I am using csv2rec to read csv file. Many fields in that csv file are named like "MS1-API2_C". When this field is read by csv2rec, this field name is being converted to "ms1api2_c". Now I can not access this column elements by using converted field name or original field name. Please suggest solutions.

Answer (score 2):

`csv2rec` is designed to automatically lowercase headers, but you can get around this feature by using the following approach:

```
import matplotlib.mlab
import csv

filename = 'input.csv'

with open(filename, 'r') as f_input:
    headers = next(csv.reader(f_input))

data = matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec(filename, names=headers)
```

To quote from the Matplotlib [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec):

> The headers will be lower cased, spaces will be converted to
>   underscores, and illegal attribute name characters removed.

Comment: I tried the suggestion but it shows  line 401, in __new__
    self = ndarray.__new__(subtype, shape, (record, descr), order=order) Showing MemoryError

Comment: You will need to ensure all of your headers have suitable names. Try simplifying them for a test to see if the issue goes away. I also suggest you do `print headers` to see if they have been read in correctly.

Comment: print header is working fine. I did for test  and it is working ok. but for actual file it is not working. Could it be the length of field names?

Comment: This [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#validating-names) might help. I don't think length is an issue.